# Wiring Flash Chip to Raspberry Pi

Tags: firmware, memory, flash, memory-dump

I'm trying to wire a [Winbond W25Q128FV](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q128fv_revhh1_100913_website1.pdf) to my [Rasberry Pi Model 1B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/) so that I can dump the firmware. I'll be using an SOIC8 clip and probe cables.

Here is what I'm thinking:

**Flash** ----- **rPi**

CS ----- CS0

DO ----- MISO

WP ----- ??

GND ----- GND

VCC ----- 3V3

HOLD ----- ??

CLK ----- SCLK

DI ----- MOSI

I've read that WP and HOLD/RESET should also be connected to 3V3, but there's only 2 3V3 pins on my pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use WP and HOLD at all. It will work without.
You can try without first. Is write protect enabled?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check?

Comment: Reading the data sheet of the flash, that you linked it looks like you don't need to use WP and Hold, if you only need to dump the flash. You can run flashrom without attaching those pins. The VCC 3.3v is Okay.

Comment: I think on flash you can turn off write protect, should be a register.